# Kubernetes Service connect with TargetPort rather then NodePort

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-servicev1
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
      nodePort: 30009
  selector:
    k8s-app: v1
```

After creating service I am able to curl with target port 5000 but not with nodePort 30009 it timesout.

Comment: What is the URL you used for `curl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant write answer more concrete without answering you to comments, but..most probably your access something wrong.

Usually minikube has ip 192.168.99.100 and sometimes it is different in rare cases. You can check it with `minikube ip` command.
After you create deployment and `Nodeport` type service - it should be accessible by opening `{minikube ip}:{nodePort}` address.

If you created everything right, `curl {minikube ip}:30009` should work fine for you.

Also, to be 100% sure, you can always hit

1. `minikube service <SERVICE_NAME> --url` to receive proper url
2. `minikube service <SERVICE_NAME>` to open it

In your case:

```
minikube service myapp-servicev1 --url
minikube service myapp-servicev1
```